# Error resolving template [create], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: spring-boot, templates, controller, thymeleaf, http-status-code-500

I can't figure out why I keep getting this status = 500 template error.

''There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template [create], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [create], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers''

I tried looking up resources and I coundn't resolve it.

This is what IntelliJ is saying:
[image]

This is my create.html template:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head th:replace="fragments :: head"></head>
<head>
    <link th:href="@{/css/meetups.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body class="create-meetup-body">
    <header th:replace="fragments :: header"></header>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <ul class="meetup-nav">
                    <li><a href="/meetups" class="all-cta">All Meetups</a>
                        <a href="/meetups/create" class="primary-cta">Create a Meetup</a>
                        <a href="/meetups/delete" class="secondary-cta">Delete a Meetup</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="create-meetup-section">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-wrapper">
                    <label class="form-name">Meetup Name:
                            <input th:field="${meetup.meetupName}" class="form-control">
                    </label>
                        <p class="error" th:errors="${meetup.meetupName}"></p>
                    <label class="form-email">Contact Email:
                        <input th:field="${meetup.meetupContactEmail}" class="form-control">
                    </label>
                        <p class="error" th:errors="${meetup.meetupContactEmail}"></p>
                    <!--label class="form-date">Date:
                        <input type="date" class="form-control">
                    </label-->
                    <label class="form-date">Date (mm/dd/yyy):
                        <input th:field="${meetup.meetupDate}" class="form-control">
                    </label>
                        <p class="error" th:errors="${meetup.meetupDate}"></p>
                    <label class="form-description">Description:
                            <textarea th:field="${meetup.meetupDescription}" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </label>
                        <p class="error" th:errors="${meetup.meetupDescription}"></p>

                    <label class="form-category" th:for="category">Category:</label>
                    <select id="meetupCategory" name="meetupCategory">
                        <option value="Nature Walk">Nature Walk</option>
                        <option value="Cycling">Cycling</option>
                        <option value="Family Activity">Family Activity</option>
                        <option value="Athletic">Athletic</option>
                    </select>

                    <label class="form-trail" th:for="trail">Trail:</label>
                        <select name="trailId">
                            <option th:each="trail : ${trails}"
                                    th:text="${trail.name}"
                                    th:value="${trail.id}"></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Create Meetup">
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I believe create.html it's in the correct directory:

[image]

This is my controller class:

```
@RequestMapping("meetups")
public class MeetupController {

    @Autowired
    private MeetupRepository meetupRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TrailRepository trailRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationController authenticationController;

    @GetMapping
    public String displayMeetups(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            User theUser = authenticationController.getUserFromSession(session);
            model.addAttribute("theUser", theUser);
        }

        model.addAttribute("title", "Trail Meetups");
        model.addAttribute("meetups", meetupRepository.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("trails", trailRepository.findAll());
        return "meetups/index";
    }


    @GetMapping("create")
    public String displayCreateMeetupsForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Create A New Meetup");
        model.addAttribute("trails", trailRepository.findAll());
        model.addAttribute(new Meetup());
        return "meetups/create";
    }


    @PostMapping("create")
    public String processCreateMeetupsForm(@ModelAttribute @Valid Meetup newMeetup,
                                           Errors errors, Model model, @RequestParam int trailId) {


        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("title", "Create A New Meetup");
            return "create";
        }
        Optional<Trail> trailObjs = trailRepository.findById(trailId);
        if (trailObjs.isPresent()) {
            Trail trail = trailObjs.get();
            model.addAttribute("trail", trail);
            model.addAttribute("trailId", trailId);
            newMeetup.setTrail(trail);

            meetupRepository.save(newMeetup);
            model.addAttribute("meetups", meetupRepository.findAll());
            return "meetups/index";
        } else {
            return "redirect:";
        }

    }

    @GetMapping("delete")
    public String displayDeleteMeetupsForm(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            User theUser = authenticationController.getUserFromSession(session);
            model.addAttribute("theUser", theUser);
        }

        model.addAttribute("title", "Delete A Meetup");
        model.addAttribute("meetups", meetupRepository.findAll());
        return "meetups/delete";
    }

    @PostMapping("delete")
    public String processDeleteMeetupsForm(@RequestParam(required = false) int[] meetupIds, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            User theUser = authenticationController.getUserFromSession(session);
            model.addAttribute("theUser", theUser);
        }

        if (meetupIds != null) {
            for (int id : meetupIds) {
                meetupRepository.deleteById(id);
            }
        }
        return "redirect:";
    }

    @GetMapping("details")
    public String displayMeetupDetails(@RequestParam Integer meetupId, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            User theUser = authenticationController.getUserFromSession(session);
            model.addAttribute("theUser", theUser);
        }

        Optional<Meetup> result = meetupRepository.findById(meetupId);
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            model.addAttribute("title", "Invalid: A meetup with ID " + meetupId + "does not seem to exist.");
        } else {
            Meetup meetup = result.get();
            model.addAttribute("title", meetup.getMeetupName() + " Details");
            model.addAttribute("meetups", meetup);
            model.addAttribute("trails", trailRepository.findAll());
        }

        return "meetups/details";
    }
```

[image]